Is there any public datasets for predictive maintenance/anomaly detection related to AS/RS or Warehouse Automation Systems?
I'm working on my master's thesis, which focuses on developing a predictive maintenance system to predict failures for automated storage and retrieval systems (AS/RS) or intralogistics systems in general. For those unfamiliar with AS/RS, examples include: Overhead Conveyor Systems, Automated Guided Vehicles (AGV), or Stacker Crane.
To carry out my research, I need datasets with sensor data that include variables like:

Motor vibration
Wheel wear
Motor temperature
Motor electric current
Conveyor belt tension
Failure data
And other related metrics

If you know of any publicly available datasets related to this topic, I would be incredibly grateful if you could share them.
